# Ionic 4 simple tab in blank project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs, ionic-tabs

I have create a new project with `ionic start myApp blank`

Now i need to add tab in to the project i have create folder tabs in pages and create two file inside tabs `tabs.html` `tabs.ts`
in tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="homePage" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="bulb" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="reclamationsPage" tabTitle="Reclamations" tabIcon="settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

in tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ReclamationsPage } from '../reclamations/reclamations';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})
export class TabsPage {

  reclamationsPage: ReclamationsPage;
  homePage: HomePage;
}
```

in app.module.ts
i have add

```
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    ReclamationsPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    LoginPage,
    ReclamationsPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
```

and in app.component.ts i have change `rootPage:any` with `rootPage:any = TabsPage;`

but when i excute my code ionic serve i have noting in screen blank page look the image[image]

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\android\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\android\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tabs.html;

```
<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="myIndex">
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabIcon="star"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

> tabs.ts

```
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html',
})

export class TabsPage{
    tab1Root = 'ReclamationsPage';
    tab2Root = 'HomePage';
    myIndex: number;
}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){
    this.myIndex = navParams.data.tabIndex || 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi its work now i have to change this tab1Root = ReclamationsPage;
    tab2Root = HomePage;  thank you you make me happy :)

Comment: Just fyi; with [4.0.0-beta.18](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta18-2018-12-13) the usage of ion-tab was removed and it's not necessary to use named outlets.**Current Demo** (@ionic/angular 4.0.1) + **Explanation** can be found [here](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tab-routing/).