# ionic 3 Tab not focusing on particular tab1Root while loading

Tags: angular, html, typescript, ionic3

I am using ion-tabs in my app.
When i navigating from 2nd tabs sup page to tabs, it loading the tab1Root page, but tab focused on 2nd tab.

Here is my code:

```
 dismiss() {
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage).then(() => {
      const index = this.viewCtrl.index;
      this.navCtrl.remove(index);
  });
  }
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="My Booking" tabIcon="book"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="chatbubbles"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

I am navigating to tabs page at dismiss() from [root]="tab2Root". My tab will be in 2nd tab. I need it to focus at first tab when i call dismiss(). and 2nd tab will me in tab2Root page

Comment: Do you want the color of the selected tab to be obvious?

Comment: I need the selected tab should be my 1st tab . I tried "this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(TabsPage)" , but it hiding my side menu.

Comment: and i tried "this.parent.select(0)" . It getting my 1st tab, but the second tab showing sub page. I need the second tab to show my tab2Root page

Comment: can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52939125/ionic-4-simple-tab-in-blank-project/52945197#52945197) ?

Comment: tried it, but not working